# Upgrading Bluetooth earbuds case battery

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, charger, lipo

Recently I got Chinese true wireless earbuds called Redmi AirDots. It has 3.7V 300mAh Li-Po battery in it's charging/carrier box that I want to replace with the one with higher capacity. I opened the box to get to the board so that I can identify the battery controller chip to check compatibility. The problem is that, it's a Chinese product so the chips has no datasheet or any info available online. There are three chips on the board & one of them must be battery controller but I can not identify which one is it. There are some numbers printed on all these chips that I have mentioned in attached image.
So I need confirm these two points

1. Can I replace battery with higher capacity one without worrying about the compatibility of the battery controller on the board?
2. If I must use battery compatible with my board, then how can I get information of that chip?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: try drawing a schematic diagram

Comment: All I want is to identify the charging IC and some info about it. I think battery doesn't have to do anything with other components of the schematic. Moreover, it's not an open source board. So it's very difficult to get is schematic.

Answer (score 3):

You're fine to pop in a single cell lipo with higher capacity. It might not charge at the fastest speed possible for the replacement battery, but other than that the electronics on that board won't care.

Comment: You mean all I need to care about is that it must be 3.7V single lipo cell. Right? I think the charge current will remain the same hence it will take more time for charging.

Comment: Yep it'll take longer to charge, but that's to be expected.